# Regex number extraction

Tags: regex

I have those tags in a text pulled from database
[ATTACH=CONFIG]9[/ATTACH] and I am trying to extract the number, 9 in that case.

My first try

```
$images = preg_match_all(#\[ATTACH.*?\[/ATTACH\]#si, $article['pagetext'], $images['matches']);
    $image = $images['matches'][1][0];
```

is not returning anything.

Can someone please help me with proper regex? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the following code with php5.4.5:

```
    <?php
$article = array();
$article['pagetext'] = '[ATTACH=CONFIG]9[/ATTACH][ATTACH=CONFIG]10[/ATTACH]';
$images = array();
$images['matches'] = array();
if(preg_match_all('/[ATTACH[^\]]*\](\d+)\[\/ATTACH\]/i', $article['pagetext'], $images['matches']) > 0){
    # will print out "9", "10"
    for($i = 0; $i < count($images['matches'][1]); ++$i)
        printf("%s\n", $images['matches'][1][$i]);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression

```
#([0-9]+)#
```

would be better.

The result will be in `$images['matches'][1]`.

If you need only that numbers that are inside `ATTACH` tags:

```
#\[ATTACH[^]]*]([0-9]+)\[/ATTACH]#
```

Comment: Thank you. $images = preg_match_all('#\[ATTACH[^]]*]([0-9]+)\[/ATTACH]#', $images['matches']); tells me Warning: preg_match_all() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given